# How to allow any user (including those added in future), group or windows user to create new tables in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to figure it out using SQL script, but I need also do it in SQL Server Management Studio.

I can grant permission to create tables with this script, but only for specified users.

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO user_name;
GO
```

Comment: You can grant permissions to windows/AD groups, but not to not yet existing logins I think. What is the use case?

Comment: You can grant that permission to the database role `public`. By default, any new users are assigned to public role and therefore they will have the desired permission.